# How get a blob to save on database with PHP, from a BLOB URL?

Tags: php, mysql, url, blob

I have a Blob Url like this: blob:http%3A//localhost/539c9a90-5356-4e04-8571-d0b420567271 
How can I create a Blob from this in PHP? I have to save a blob file on a MySql Database.

Comment: blob is a field type in mysql. treat it pretty much like any other field type in mysql. but why use a blob for what looks to be text only? blobs are for BINARY data, and you're just saving text.

Comment: BLOB stands for Binary Large Object. It is meant to store binary data like images or pdf.